# API ISSUE Call Handshake

Tags: bigcommerce

THIS IS MY ISSUE PLEASE HELP. When i run my run.bat this is what i get in response.  Im not sure what is the best way to fix this or if it is on my side of the code.. nothing has changed on my side so im assuming its on your side that it just broke?

```
E:\WebsiteIntegration>.\php\php.exe -f main.php
2015-09-25 14:15:16 Edge to Bigcommerce Website Integration v0.8.4
2015-09-25 14:15:16 Processing items that have been updated since 2015-09-22                    11:
10:49
2015-09-25 14:15:16 Connecting to integration database... SUCCESS
2015-09-25 14:15:16 Connecting to The Edge database... SUCCESS
2015-09-25 14:15:16 Checking connection to Bigcommerce.
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Bigcommerce\Api\NetworkError' with     message
'error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake     failu
re' in E:\WebsiteIntegration\lib\bigcommerce.php:82
Stack trace:
#0 E:\WebsiteIntegration\lib\bigcommerce.php(142):      Bigcommerce\Api\Connection->h
andleResponse()
#1 E:\WebsiteIntegration\lib\bigcommerce.php(398):      Bigcommerce\Api\Connection->g
et('https://www.hop...')
#2 E:\WebsiteIntegration\lib\bigcommerce.php(662):    Bigcommerce\Api\Client::getTi
me()
#3 E:\WebsiteIntegration\main.php(1534):      Bigcommerce\Api\Client::getRequestsRema
ining()
#4 {main}
thrown in E:\WebsiteIntegration\lib\bigcommerce.php on line 82

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Bigcommerce\Api\NetworkError' with message     'err
or:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake      failure' i
n E:\WebsiteIntegration\lib\bigcommerce.php:82
Stack trace:
#0 E:\WebsiteIntegration\lib\bigcommerce.php(142):       Bigcommerce\Api\Connection->h
andleResponse()
#1 E:\WebsiteIntegration\lib\bigcommerce.php(398):      Bigcommerce\Api\Connection->g
et('https://www.hop...')
#2 E:\WebsiteIntegration\lib\bigcommerce.php(662):      Bigcommerce\Api\Client::getTi
me()
#3 E:\WebsiteIntegration\main.php(1534):      Bigcommerce\Api\Client::getRequestsRema
ining()
#4 {main}
```

thrown in E:\WebsiteIntegration\lib\bigcommerce.php on line 82

```
E:\WebsiteIntegration>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: This says SSL Handshake failure 

_PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Bigcommerce\Api\NetworkError' with     message 'error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake     failu re' in
 E:\WebsiteIntegration\lib\bigcommerce.php:82_ I believe your script is not able to establish Secure connection.

Answer (score 0):

From BigCommerce... Thank you for contacting Bigcommerce API support and allowing us time to look over your concern. The problem you are seeing is due to the recent deprecation of the RC4 cipher suite (please go to developer.bigcommerce.com to see the banner we posted regarding this). This is a PCI requirement change that needed to be done and we are now doing it globally to all Bigcommerce IP addresses. It is likely that your client libraries is making a specific call to use cipher. You will either need to modify the library/ scripts to not make these references or update to the latest client libraries available at https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/clients . Please let us know if there is anything else we can do to help related ot this case. As always, please don't hesitate to contact us if there any other API questions or issues you may have.

-- Unfortunately I have not been able to figure out what new Cipher to use in place of the old RC4 cipher.

Comment: awesome jason, thank you so much, is there anyway to build the script to do an api call to check for new version and if there is a new version to upgrade my libraries automatically??  Please let me know..  Thanks

Comment: If you are using the 'newest' API libraries provided by BigCommerce you shouldn't have any issues. I am not however, I'm using a package built into Laravel, so I'm having troubles fixing it for mine.

There changes just "removes" the call for a specific cipher, but doing that doesn't fix anything for me. I'm wondering if my system itself needs an update like to curl and openssl maybe?

Comment: Removing all automatic references to choosing a cipher seems to work perfectly fine for me. I just had to make sure to nab all the declarations from the extra Laravel code.

Comment: @JasonDiehl Were you able to identify which cipher the 'default' one is after you removed the automatic references? My version seems to want me to specify a specific cipher...

Comment: @dSquared I just removed the reference to use RC4, originally I thought my system wasn't matching up to anything but I found in the Laravel config that there was another place that was causing the default to RC4. If you remove all reference then by default CURL should find a match, so it asks BigC and then compares to what it has access to and then uses a match. I do not know what mine is defaulting to, sorry. You shouldn't have to define it. If you have the latest BigC code it's just not defined, if you are using Laravel the Kalley Package, I just worked with them to push a new version.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux servers running languages like PHP and Ruby that use libssl/OpenSSL, please check the supported ciphers as follows via the command line:

```
~$ openssl ciphers -v
 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
AES256-SHA              SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
```

You need to change your cipher to one of these. Hope it helps